# How to improve/modify parameters of Feature Matching - SIFT SURF - Opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to use feature matching to determine if two images are similar. I have tried SIFT, SURF, and ORB with similar results from each. I am first trying to display the matches between these two images. [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvlbA.png) [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9rl4.png) I have tried both brute force matching and knn matching but with both implementations, I get around 10 matches with little to no [accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15M5I.png). Are the two images too different in terms of scale, transformation, and perspective to generate accurate matches? What parameters could I modify to improve performance? The matching often produces a lot of matches but only a few pass ratio test.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

model = cv2.imread("path")
modelg = cv2.cvtColor(model,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
modelg = cv2.GaussianBlur(modelg,(7,7),0)
height, width = modelg.shape[:2]
print(str(height)+ " " + str(width))


frame = cv2.imread("Path")
plt.imshow(frame)
plt.show()

#frame = cv2.imread("Path")

frame = cv2.resize(frame,(width,height))
frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame,(7,7),0)


#blur = cv2.blur(frame,(7,7))
plt.imshow(blur,cmap='gray')
plt.show()
plt.imshow(modelg,cmap='gray')
plt.show()

# Initiate SIFT detector
surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create()
# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
orb = cv2.ORB_create()
# find the keypoints and descriptors with ORB
kp1, des1 = surf.detectAndCompute(modelg,None)
kp2, des2 = surf.detectAndCompute(blur,None)
#kp1, des1 = surf.detectAndCompute(,None)
#kp2, des2 = surf.detectAndCompute(blur,None)
# BFMatcher with default params

bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = bf.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)
print(len(matches))
# Apply ratio test
good = []
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.75*n.distance:
        good.append([m])
print(len(good))
# cv.drawMatchesKnn expects list of lists as matches.
img3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(modelg,kp1,blur,kp2,good,None,flags=cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)
plt.imshow(img3),plt.show()
```

Comment: I do not think they contain enough features (corners) that are distinct from each other to provide enough good points to do a match.

Comment: Would matchShapes be a better method to compare the general shape of the objects?

Comment: It depends upon the shapes you have to match. Typically it is done on binary shapes, though it can be done on grayscale. See https://www.learnopencv.com/shape-matching-using-hu-moments-c-python/

Comment: What comparison method would you recommend to determine the similarity of images like the ones above? I am also looking to compare images of an octopus object and objects with text.